# How to rotate p-values on multi-group pairwise t-test plot p-values from the stat_compare_means {ggpubr} function

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, boxplot, ggpubr

**Hi dear community of stack overflow,**

I am having trouble finding ways of rotating my p-values in my multi-group parwise t-test plot.

My p-values generated with the `stat_compare_means {ggpubr}` function is overlapping and I would like to rotate them, so that they are horizontally printed on the multiples-plot. Any help on this is highly appreciated!

I have generated a subset of the original data and hope it is useful to reproduce the issue...

Thank you!

**Trying to add the argument: angle = 90**

```
##########################################################################################################
# Libraries

library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggpubr)
#> Warning: package 'ggpubr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.2
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.6.2
# install.packages("datapasta") 
# I have been using the datapasta package to generate a little subset of the data
library(datapasta)

##########################################################################################################
# Data

# Original data
dim(agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline) 
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline' not found
  #  [1] 159705      4


dp_set_max_rows(300) # here im just setting a higher threshold for the dpaste function..

# Creating s little subset (reprex data) by randomly selecting 200 rows from the original data
agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline.reprex <- agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline %>%
  slice_sample(n = 200) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  dpasta()
#> Error in slice_sample(., n = 200): object 'agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline' not found

##########################################################################################################


agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline.reprex <- tibble::tribble(
                                                                                                                         ~variables, ~logRR_EQR_group,           ~value,   ~hline,
                                                                                                                    "iSDA_log_eCEC",         "5.high",               NA, 22.95124,
                                                                                                                    "Bio09_MT_DryQ",         "5.high", 21.4500007629395, 21.36496,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_log_C_tot",       "4.medium",           28.752, 28.79699,
                                                                                                                        "Bio07_TAR",       "4.medium", 21.5999984741211, 17.76082,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",       "4.medium", 24.5166664123535, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_log_C_tot",       "4.medium",           22.586, 28.79699,
                                                                                                                "Bio14_Precip_DryM",       "4.medium",                9, 22.76028,
                                                                                                                "iSDA_FE_Bulk_dens",       "4.medium",          144.566, 137.4864,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_CLAY_conc",       "4.medium",           19.604, 28.45441,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_CLAY_conc",         "5.high",           35.598, 28.45441,
                                                                                                                        "Bio03_Iso",       "4.medium", 57.1151666641235, 67.35677,
                                                                                                                 "Bio12_Pecip_Annu",       "4.medium",              737, 1106.095,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Mg",       "4.medium",            45.69, 48.73153,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_S",     "2.very_low",            17.79, 18.95376,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",       "4.medium",               25, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                        "Bio07_TAR",       "4.medium", 15.4798449952473, 17.76082,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_CLAY_conc",       "4.medium",           23.566, 28.45441,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Fe",         "5.high",           38.788,  36.9393,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_SAND_conc",       "4.medium",           46.908, 52.24636,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_P",       "4.medium",           19.406, 21.53198,
                                                                                                                "Bio13_Precip_WetM",       "4.medium",               68, 194.3711,
                                                                                                                    "Bio10_MT_WarQ",       "4.medium", 21.4500007629395, 23.14786,
                                                                                                                "Bio17_Precip_DryQ",          "3.low", 260.133333333333, 94.43099,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Ca",          "3.low",           76.366, 63.25199,
                                                                                                                    "iSDA_log_eCEC",         "5.high",           20.284, 22.95124,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_P",       "4.medium",           19.512, 21.53198,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",       "4.medium", 11.5833339691162, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_N",          "3.low",           29.086, 59.67384,
                                                                                                                "Bio14_Precip_DryM",    "6.very_high",                2, 22.76028,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Fe",         "5.high",           38.788,  36.9393,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",       "4.medium", 14.0791666507721, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_N",       "4.medium",           69.186, 59.67384,
                                                                                                            "iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock",       "4.medium",              200,  198.785,
                                                                                                                     "iSDA_log_SOC",       "4.medium",            17.84, 20.34465,
                                                                                                                      "ASTER_Slope",         "5.high",             1.64, 2.676804,
                                                                                                                "Bio17_Precip_DryQ",         "5.high",           114.25, 94.43099,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_SAND_conc",       "4.medium",           33.942, 52.24636,
                                                                                                                   "Bio15_Precip_S",         "5.high", 62.4644813537598, 66.95945,
                                                                                                                    "Bio11_MT_ColQ",    "6.very_high",               22, 18.12413,
                                                                                                                        "Bio03_Iso",       "4.medium", 76.5648231506348, 67.35677,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Ca",       "4.medium",           61.956, 63.25199,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",       "4.medium", 15.9499998092651, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                        "Bio03_Iso",          "3.low", 83.0484390258789, 67.35677,
                                                                                                                    "Bio09_MT_DryQ",         "5.high", 21.4500007629395, 21.36496,
                                                                                                                     "Bio06_MinTCM",         "5.high", 20.2000007629395,  12.0894,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",       "4.medium",               NA, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                         "Bio04_TS",       "4.medium", 92.7229080200195, 206.4425,
                                                                                                                        "Bio07_TAR",       "4.medium", 21.5999984741211, 17.76082,
                                                                                                                "Bio13_Precip_WetM",       "4.medium",              175, 194.3711,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_S",       "4.medium",               NA, 18.95376,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_S",       "4.medium",             13.6, 18.95376,
                                                                                                                    "iSDA_log_eCEC",       "4.medium",           18.602, 22.95124,
                                                                                                                "Bio14_Precip_DryM",       "4.medium", 22.5115384615385, 22.76028,
                                                                                                                     "iSDA_log_SOC",       "4.medium",           23.876, 20.34465,
                                                                                                                   "Bio15_Precip_S",       "4.medium", 46.6489143371582, 66.95945,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",         "5.high", 9.34166622161865, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",          "3.low",  14.502082824707, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_K",       "4.medium",           49.252,  44.7684,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_CLAY_conc",       "4.medium",           19.604, 28.45441,
                                                                                                                    "iSDA_log_eCEC",       "4.medium",           18.164, 22.95124,
                                                                                                                     "iSDA_log_SOC",       "4.medium",           16.766, 20.34465,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_S",       "4.medium",            22.45, 18.95376,
                                                                                                                        "Bio05_TWM",       "4.medium", 28.3999996185303, 29.85022,
                                                                                                                   "Bio15_Precip_S",       "4.medium", 116.536264419556, 66.95945,
                                                                                                                   "ASTER_Altitude",       "4.medium",          1661.33, 864.0325,
                                                                                                            "iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock",       "4.medium",           199.99,  198.785,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",    "6.very_high", 21.6333332061768, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                     "iSDA_log_SOC",       "4.medium",           17.732, 20.34465,
                                                                                                                     "Bio06_MinTCM",       "4.medium", 15.3000001907349,  12.0894,
                                                                                                            "iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock",       "4.medium",           199.95,  198.785,
                                                                                                                        "Bio05_TWM",          "3.low", 36.7000007629395, 29.85022,
                                                                                                                          "iSDA_pH",       "4.medium",           57.428, 58.60272,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",       "4.medium", 12.8000001907349, 11.39247,
                                                                                                            "iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock",       "4.medium",            179.4,  198.785,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_SAND_conc",         "5.high",           29.592, 52.24636,
                                                                                                                        "Bio02_MDR",       "4.medium", 7.75208342075348, 11.39247,
                                                                                                                    "Bio11_MT_ColQ",       "4.medium", 22.4333333969116, 18.12413,
                                                                                                                      "ASTER_Slope",          "3.low",             4.15, 2.676804,
                                                                                                                    "iSDA_log_eCEC",         "5.high",           23.772, 22.95124,
                                                                                                            "iSDA_Depth_to_bedrock",         "5.high",           195.69,  198.785,
                                                                                                                "Bio14_Precip_DryM",         "5.high",               20, 22.76028,
                                                                                                                "Bio16_Precip_WetQ",       "4.medium",  19.746835443038, 495.4428,
                                                                                                                   "Bio15_Precip_S",       "4.medium", 64.6761016845703, 66.95945,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",          "3.low", 22.3500003814697, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_SILT_conc",         "5.high",           13.486, 16.79565,
                                                                                                                     "Bio06_MinTCM",       "4.medium", 6.80000019073486,  12.0894,
                                                                                                                        "Bio03_Iso",         "5.high",  51.929012298584, 67.35677,
                                                                                                                "Bio17_Precip_DryQ",       "4.medium", 201.281374654802, 94.43099,
                                                                                                                     "iSDA_log_SOC",         "5.high",           16.338, 20.34465,
                                                                                                                "Bio16_Precip_WetQ",         "5.high",              341, 495.4428,
                                                                                                                    "Bio08_MT_WetQ",         "5.high", 21.2958335876465, 19.91485,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_CLAY_conc",     "2.very_low",           20.782, 28.45441,
                                                                                                                       "iSDA_log_K",       "4.medium",            46.93,  44.7684,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Ca",         "5.high",           59.062, 63.25199,
                                                                                                                "Bio16_Precip_WetQ",       "4.medium",              418, 495.4428,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Fe",       "4.medium",           36.308,  36.9393,
                                                                                                                   "iSDA_SAND_conc",         "5.high",            56.02, 52.24636,
                                                                                                                      "iSDA_log_Mg",         "5.high",            42.02, 48.73153,
                                                                                                                    "Bio09_MT_DryQ",       "4.medium", 24.1458330154419, 21.36496,
                                                                                                                "Bio13_Precip_WetM",          "3.low",           313.25, 194.3711
                                                                                                            )
    
###############################################################################################################

# Create multi-panel Boxplots with t-test p-values
logRR_EQR_group_comparisons <- list(c("1.extremely_low", "2.very_low"),
                                    c("2.very_low", "3.low"), 
                                    c("3.low", "4.medium"), 
                                    c("4.medium", "5.high"),
                                    c("5.high", "6.very_high"),
                                    c("6.very_high", "7.extremely_high"),
                                    c("7.extremely_high", "1.extremely_low"))

# Colour range with 35 levels
nb.cols.35 <- 35
era.af.colors.35 <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(8, "Set2"))(nb.cols.35)


ttest.pair.plot.discretized.logRR.biophy.pred <- 
  ggpubr::ggboxplot(agrofor.biophys.modelling.data.long.hline.reprex,
                    "logRR_EQR_group", "value",
                    color = "variables", palette = era.af.colors.35, add = "jitter", add.params = list(size = 0.2, jitter = 0.3),
                    title = "Differences in discretized logRR values based on equal range, for each biophysical predictor",
                    bxp.errorbar = TRUE, bxp.errorbar.width = 0.5, outlier.shape = 10) + 
  facet_wrap(variables ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  theme_lucid() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1), legend.position = "none") +
  xlab("Biophysical co-variates/predictors") +
  ylab("logRR") +
  font("title", size = 20, color = "black") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = hline), linetype = 2) +
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "t.test", ref.group = ".all.", label.y = - 1) +
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = logRR_EQR_group_comparisons, label.y = -5, mapping = aes(label = sprintf("p = %5.4f", as.numeric(..p.format..), angle = 90)))  

#> Error in theme_lucid(): could not find function "theme_lucid"
```

[image: The plot I get. You can see that the p-values are horisontal and overlapping. This is what I am looking forward to solve..]

Comment: Thank you @MarcoSandri this was also the obvious attempt for me.. but I had no luck with this. Absolutely nothing happened.. It creates the plot but with no change on the p-values angle..

Comment: I found this ::

`# Change the orientation angle of the p-values
# Adjust the position of p-values using vjust and hjust
# Add more spaces between labels and the plot border
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(
    stat.test, label = "p.adj", tip.length = 0.01,
    coord.flip = TRUE, angle = 0, 
    hjust = 0, vjust = c(0, 1.2, 0)
    ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.3))) + 
  coord_flip() `

Here: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-add-p-values-onto-horizontal-ggplots/ 

but its manually set. I dont want that

Comment: I know that I can change the vertical position with the `label.y` argument but I am more interested in changing the orientation/ angle of the p-values

Comment: Thank you @MarcoSandri for your persistent assistance on this issue of mine! I thought so, yes. But I tried a couple of times – even before writing this help request. I don't get why I cannot get it to work on my side. I will try again..

Comment: Please Magnus, could you try this simple code? https://pastebin.com/vQQK9L42  You should see 3  annotations for p-values (2 "ns" rotated by 90 degrees and 1 p=0.064 rotated by 45 degrees). Let me know.

Comment: Thank you  @MarcoSandri I could reproduce your example. Now I will let you know whether it works in my own code. Have a nice day!